# Solidity: How to pass an array of addresses from one contract (NFT) to another one (not NFT) for later use?

Tags: import, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, nft

I have a simplest nft code. My task is to take an array of buyers (wallet addresses) of this nft when it's minted and to pass it ((array) or them ((addresses))) to another contract of mine, so i could take further action with them. The answer is... HOW?
I'm new to programming, so please be gentle with me ^_^

Thank you in advance!

Andrew

Nft code ->

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.8;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract Nft is ERC721 {
    string public constant TOKEN_URI =
        "ipfs://...";
    uint256 private s_tokenCounter;

    constructor() ERC721("NFT", "NFT") {
        s_tokenCounter = 0;
    }

    function mintNft() public {
        s_tokenCounter = s_tokenCounter + 1;
        _safeMint(msg.sender, s_tokenCounter);
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view override returns (string memory) {
        // require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token");
        return TOKEN_URI;
    }

    function getTokenCounter() public view returns (uint256) {
        return s_tokenCounter;
    }
}
```

I tried  to build a getter function but got lost in the code and advices.
Tried to import an NFT-contract into an executive contract...
Full of mistakes and disappointment.

Comment: Can you please specify what do you mean by "buyers"? Are you looking for the list of all historic owners (including those that don't own the token anymore), all minters (i.e. addresses that executed the `mintNft()` function), only aggregated list of current owners reflected in the other contract, list of all users who received the NFT only via OpenSea or other specific marketplace at any time (and excluding users who only received it using another way), ... ?

Comment: @Petr Hejda, hi! Thak you for paying attention to my question. I want to make NFT with minting function and collect the addresses of exactly those, who minted the NFT. I mean those, who are directly purchasing my nft from the market. Next, i want my other contract to be able to interact with these addresses.

Comment: @PetrHejda, in my case the market is OpenSea (i'm sorry, can't edit last comment).

Answer (score 1):

Here is your contract with array of addresses and its interface.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

interface InterfaceParentContract {

    function viewMyArr() external view returns(address[] memory);

} 

contract ParentContract {
    address[] public myArr;  

    constructor () {
        myArr.push(0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2);
        myArr.push(0x4B20993Bc481177ec7E8f571ceCaE8A9e22C02db);
        myArr.push(0x78731D3Ca6b7E34aC0F824c42a7cC18A495cabaB);
    } 

    function viewMyArr() external view returns(address[] memory) {
        return myArr; 
    }
}
```

And here we have another smart contract that interact with first one via interface(InterfaceParentContract)

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

import "./ParentContract.sol"; 

contract Child {

    address[] public newArr; 

    address parentContract; 

    constructor(address _address) {
        parentContract = _address; 
    }

    function smth() public  {
        InterfaceParentContract b =  InterfaceParentContract(parentContract); 
        newArr = b.viewMyArr();    
    }
}
```

So, after using smth() function your array now copied into other contract where you can operate with it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your time, but we are talking about a little different things. I'm trying to make a "thing" that will store the wallet addresses of people that are minting nft and then sending these addresses as an array to another contract for further usage.

Comment: I allready have a constructor in my second contract (VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinatorV2) from CHainlink API) so i don't really know, how to combine it with the interface constructor... Also while creating an interface i've got stuck with some "payable" methods as like the array that's creating, the addresses are not payable, but in future i need to use them in payable. So... i'm still trying to figure these things up.

Answer (score 0):

[Petr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18125566/petr-galushkin) gave an awesome answer! I made this video showing that it works as expected. If you try to read 'newArr' from the ChildContract BEFORE you execute smth(), it's an error. But if you execute smth(), then it copies the address from the ParentContract and 'newArr' becomes readable within the ChildContract. Check it out here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1l7fqgN2yrU

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your time, but we are talking about a little different things. I'm trying to make a "thing" that will store the wallet addresses of people that are minting nft and then sending these addresses as an array to another contract for further usage.

Comment: I allready have a constructor in my second contract (VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinatorV2) from CHainlink API) so i don't really know, how to combine it with the interface constructor... Also while creating an interface i've got stuck with some "payable" methods as like the array that's creating, the addresses are not payable, but in future i need to use them in payable. So... i'm still trying to figure these things up.